# Custom content plugin for front page in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

Is there any plugin available which I can use to post custom content on My front page?? I am using front page which has link to other blog pages. I want to put custom content on this front page but i am unable to find any plugin.

whatever plugins which i searched gives this facility for sidebar in a widget format there were no option for manually putting content in my theme.

Also is it possible to put latest post by a particular author on this page??

Comment: I got 1 plugin for latest post by author http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/latest-posts-by-author/?topic_id=9430 and it works fine now i want something for custom content now please help

Comment: try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-file-maker/

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom loops using `query_posts()` to build custom blocks of latest posts etc and create a file called front-page.php which will be the template for the front page of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a combination of the 'Frontpage Manager', the 'Dynamic Widgets' plugins and stylesheet overrides to manage my frontpage content. However, what you're asking for you can do by simply using the `is_front_page()` conditional tag in your theme files.

Comment: `is_home()` would refer to the posts page, `is_front_page()` would need to be used for the front page.

Comment: Oops, you're right...changed.

Comment: hi this plugins are good but my requirement is little different I just want 1 plugin which can post a content from database, i need 1 backend in settings page where i can change or add data into it